# How to correctly handle pre-authentication failures in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm implementing an application that has a variety of ways to login, most importantly via a request header for pre-auth purposes and normal username/password. Currently everything works, but I've been requested to redirect the user to an error page if they attempted to use the pre-auth filter and it "failed".

From what I can tell, if pre-auth returns null it just assumes non-authed and continues the flow. I'm looking for a way to redirect or raise an exception, but I can't seem to hit my `AuthenticationFailureHandler` from the pre-auth filter. Is there a better way to do this? Do I need to hack something together that optionally treats the `principal` as an `Exception`. Should I be using a different authentication mechanism?

I'm by no means am Spring Security expert, so any help is welcome.

I cannot share the code due to contractual agreements, but here's an example:

```java
@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
  Object principal = null;

  // Try login stuff if token exists...
  String token = request.getHeader("the-token-key");
  if (token != null && !token.empty()) {
    ...

    // If successful, correctly set principal
    principal = ...;

    // Else login failed, redirect or throw exception??
  }

  return principal;
}
```

Comment: I can't share the entire file due to the contract, but it's a `public class FoobarPreAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` which overrides the `protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request)` method, which is the example from above.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of pre-auth. If you use pre-auth it is not possible that you get any request that is not authenticated. The assumption is that a proxy or the container already did the authentication.

Comment: I fully suspect I'm misusing features (I was copying an already existing example in our codebase). Do you have some direction I can look for a way that would allow me to attempt authentication with a request header value and redirect if failed?

Comment: You have to build your own authentication, that means you need a filter, a token and a provider. Add the filter to your filter chain. Add the provider to your filter. Pass the token from your filter to your provider. Add am authentication failure handler to your filter.